# How to write a complex join query with Ruby on Rails 5.2?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

My application manages business rules descriptions in several languages. To display the index of business rules (name and description), I need to join the BusinessRule model to the Translation model. The Translation model is polymorphic:

```
 Table name: translations

  id            :integer          not null, primary key
  document_type :string
  document_id   :bigint(8)
  field_name    :string(30)       not null
  language      :string(2)        not null
  translation   :text
  searchable    :tsvector
  created_at    :datetime         not null
  updated_at    :datetime         not null
```

To make it easier, I defined aliases of the relations to the business rules in **business_rule.rb** model:

```
  has_many :name_translations, -> { where("field_name='name'") }, class_name: 'Translation', as: :document
  has_many :description_translations, -> { where("field_name='description'") }, class_name: 'Translation', as: :document
```

To build the index, I need to left outer join the business rules with respectively name_translations and description_translations for current user's language, which becomes in SQL:

```
select BR.code, TR1.translation as name, TR2.translation as description
from dqm_app.business_rules BR
left outer join dqm_app.translations TR1 on (TR1.document_id = BR.id and TR1.field_name='name' and TR1.language='en')
left outer join dqm_app.translations TR2 on (TR2.document_id = BR.id and TR2.field_name='description' and TR2.language='en')
```

Which I try to transpose as (assuming user's language is english):

```
@business_rules = BusinessRule.left_outer_joins(:name_translations, :description_translations).
where(:name_translations.language = 'en' and description_translations.language = 'en')
```

This raises 2 issues:

> 1 - ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid (PG::AmbiguousColumn: ERROR:  column
>   reference "field_name" is ambiguous) *[of course, it appears twice in the query*]

2 - the **where** condition is incorrect, and I don't know how to build it.

Can you help me?

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1):

To resolve (1) change your scopes to use the hash syntax, Rails will then add disambiguation, eg.

```
has_many :name_translations, -> { where(field_name: 'name') }, class_name: 'Translation', as: :document
```

To resolve (2) it depends, is there a field in `BusinessRule` which has the language stored?  If there is then know that Rails will pass in the `BusinessRule` instance itself to the scope if you allow it to, so you can do something like this:

```
has_many :name_translations, -> br { where(field_name: 'name', language: br.language) }, class_name: 'Translation', as: :document
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to smathy, I finally solved the two issues:

1 - added disambiguation with hash syntax in BusinessRule model

```
has_many :name_translations, -> { where(field_name: 'name') }, class_name: 'Translation', as: :document
has_many :description_translations, -> { where(field_name: 'description') }, class_name: 'Translation', as: :document
```

2 - as the BusinessRule model does not store the language, but user's profile does, in the index method I added a where clause which refers to the *translations* table:

```
  @business_rules = BusinessRule.left_outer_joins(:name_translations, :description_translations).
    where(translations: {language: user_language})
```

Note that I did not manage to have the where clause to refer to :name_translations or :description_translations.

Comment: For what it's worth, complex queries like this can be broken down into smaller bits of logic, named, and composed just like you would do with other methods, provided you use Arel. [Thoughtbot has a nice intro on doing so here](https://thoughtbot.com/blog/using-arel-to-compose-sql-queries).